# How to manage Cisco ASA series without management cable?

Tags: firewalls, cisco

How can I manage my Cisco ASA device without the management cable?

I have not set it up at all, but I have physical access to it.

Comment: So I assume you're not able to get it onto a network? Do you know the network configuration of the management interface?

Comment: that is true, i dont know the config, all i know is that it is default, btw, this is a private lab, so i can do anything right now, it wont effect anything.

Comment: This is in no way an InfoSec question.

Comment: You're right, schroeder. For some reason I thought I saw this in server fault. Either way, StackezZ you need to RTFM. Use an ethernet cable on your laptop or desktop or what have you, plug it into the management interface, configure it so it's on the same network as the management interface, and log in.

Comment: WHaaaat this is a firewall, which goes under CNNA security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **may** be able to manage the ASA without a console cable **if** the ASA's inside interface is configured to be on a network, you can access that network, you can find its IP address, and you can guess the login credentials. This being a lab you have a better chance of guessing the credentials as they may be kept simple.

If that doesn't work then there's no other way to access the device without a console cable. If this is a lab I'd be very surprised if there wasn't a console cable somewhere. If the problem is you don't have a serial adapter for your laptop/tablet/whatever then you can run a roll-over cable from the aux port of a cisco device you can access to the console of the one you can't, configure the aux port as a serial out, you can then telnet to a local IP on that device to the aux port, and console in that way.